# Изохронная передача

Tags: usb

```
    void SendComand(byte byt[]) {
    //CreatePrinter(n);
    HANDLE event;
    HANDLE Read;
    HANDLE Write;


    OverlapWrite.OffsetHigh = 1;
    OverlapWrite.Offset = 1;
    OverlapWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, (LPCWSTR)"Read");


    OverlapRead.OffsetHigh = 1;
    OverlapRead.Offset = 1;
    OverlapRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, (LPCWSTR)"Write");

    memset(sim, 0, sizeof(sim));
    int sizebyt = sizeof(byt) - 1;

    WriteFile(ConDevice, (LPCVOID)byt, sizebyt, &ReturnedLength, &OverlapWrite);


    ReadFile(ConDevice, &sim, sizeof(sim), &ReturnedLength, &OverlapRead);
}
```

Общаюсь с устройством данным образом, подскажите это какой тип передачи данных? 
Для моей задачи нудно использовать изохронный метод, подскажите как это реализовать или где почитать. Спасибо

Comment: Тип обмена (control, interrupt, bulk, isochronous) проставляется в настройках endpoint'а в устройстве. Если endpoint не поддерживает изохрон, вы с PC никак не добьетесь от него этого режима. Если я правильно документацию помню

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов поддерживает сто процентов, потому что в прошивке в свиче сравнивается тип передачи, и уже от этого типа даются определенные возможности.

Comment: Значит, вам нужно данные слать в нужный Endpoint.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как указать конечную точку ?

Comment: Я знаю ее адрес, но где его  указать?